# Can anyone help me understand what is the use of .spread in Bluebird library

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I'm working on my first Nodejs application, someone else has developed this application before me and I'm trying to fix some issue and having trouble understanding the following.

```
return Promise.join(
        findStagingAdvanced(stagingQuery),
        findDboAdvanced(dboQuery)
    )     
    .spread((stagingIssues, dboIssues) => _.concat(dboIssues, stagingIssues))
    .then(....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a promise that is fulfilled with an array and that array has a known length, then you can use `.spread()` to convert the array to individual function arguments.  It is a substitute for `.then()` that converts the arguments from an array to individual arguments before calling your handler.

So, instead of this:

```
someFunction().then(function(arrayOfArgs) {
    let arg1 = arrayOfArgs[0];
    let arg2 = arrayOfArgs[1];
});
```

You can do this:

```
someFunction().spread(function(arg1, arg2) {
    // can directly access arg1 and arg2 here 
});
```

---

So, in your specific code example, `Promise.join()` already offers a callback that separates out the individual results so it should not be needed at all.  So, you could just do this:

```
return Promise.join(
        findStagingAdvanced(stagingQuery),
        findDboAdvanced(dboQuery),
        (stagingIssues, dboIssues) => _.concat(dboIssues, stagingIssues)
    ).then(allIssues => {
        // allIssues contains combined results of both functions above
    });
```

What this code is doing is collecting the results from `findStagingAdvanced()` and `findDboAdvanced()` and merging those results together into a single array of results.

---

It could be written in standard ES6 (e.g. without Bluebird's extra capabilities) like this:

```
 return Promise.all([findStagingAdvanced(stagingQuery), findDboAdvanced(dboQuery)])
   .then(results => results[0].concat(results[1]))
   .then(allIssues => {
        // allIssues contains combined results of both functions above
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

it allows you to get the result of `findStagingAdvanced` and `findDboAdvanced` and merge them together without intermediate variable

without spread you would have an extra variable that will be mutated :

```
var staging;
findStagingAdvanced(stagingQuery)
.then(stagingQuery => {
    staging = stagingQuery; // not that good practice
    return findDboAdvanced(dboQuery);
})
.then(dboQuery => {
    var merged = [staging, dboQuery];
    return ... // another promise that use staging and dboQuery together
})
```